How to programmatically invoke a package update in the Microsoft Store (and verify that it has updated available packages)?
Undermentioned is a paraphrased version of the code I've been able to locate (primarily from the 1st response and 3rd-to-last response to learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-technet-forums/5ac7daa9-54e6-43c0-9746-293dcb8ef2ec#all-replies-9, which requests this too):
#!/usr/bin/env -S pwsh
#Requires -PSEdition 'Core'
#Requires -Version 7

If ($IsWindows) {

    # Shared
    # ------
        $NamespaceName = 'root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap'
        $ClassName = 'MDM_EnterpriseModernAppManagement_AppManagement01'

    # DotNet Style
    # ------------
        $WMIObj = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "$NamespaceName" -Class "$ClassName"
        $Result = $WMIObj.UpdateScanMethod()

    # PowerShell Style
    # ----------------
        Get-CimInstance `
            -Namespace "$NamespaceName" `
            -ClassName "$ClassName" `
        | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName 'UpdateScanMethod'

}

Else { Exit 1 }

I expected at least one of those methods to function. However, they don't. Instead, they appear to indefinitely hang when the Microsoft Store itself is active, or output the undermentioned error otherwise:

Get-CimInstance: Access to a CIM resource was not available to the client.

The full Get-Error | Export-CLIXML output is available at /gitlab.com/-/snippets/4774462.
Consequently, I ask for a version that is known to work, and a way to verify that it has successfully performed its task (is possible).
I have heard that winget update --all might also check packages installed from the msstore repository, but I don't see any documentation stating this. All I've been able to verify is that I can utilize it to install packages from the msstore repository.

Have you tried winget yet? If you run that script line by line, at what point does it hang? Is it just taking a long time, or is the process actually hung, or is there an eventual time out? It's really only one command, that last section, so it shouldn't be difficult to debug it.

@Ramhound, my sole knowledge of an MRE is a type of ration pack that I used to eat on exercise. What do you actually refer to?

@music2myear, I'll let it run a while longer and report back. Thanks.

This condensed one-line version of the command runs fine for me, as admin (and doesn't require PSv7): Get-CimInstance -Namespace "Root\cimv2\mdm\dmmap" -ClassName "MDM_EnterpriseModernAppManagement_AppManagement01" | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName UpdateScanMethod. My store shows about 50 apps, but none of them require updates - It only took 10-20 seconds to run. If you're in windows 11, you can use Get-/Set-AppxPackageAutoUpdateSettings to see and adjust an app's update behavior

@RokeJulianLockhart - Minimal Reproduceable Example. In other words enough code to reproduce the error ourselves. Providing the code in the comment is helpful but not as helpful as editing your question. Now I am realizing that you have done that you just formatted it in a strange way. So strangely I didn't even recognized what you provided was code.

@Ramhound, it starts with a shebang, and the formatting is ultimately <pre><code>... What did you expect instead? If you copy the contents to an IDE like VSCode, you'll get syntax .PS1 highlighting too.

@RokeJulianLockhart - Oversight

@Ramhound, what?

I overlooked what you provided was a PowerShell script because of the formatting and the fact the shebang isn’t required normally with PowerShell scripts.

@Cpt.Whale, apologies for neglecting to add what was most important - the error seen after I allow it to finish (when it doesn't hang). I've updated the question to include it at /revisions/1862417/4, but summarily, the Get-Error | Export-CLIXML output can be seen at gitlab.com/-/snippets/4774462.

@Ramhound, that makes sense. The shebang was fairly redundant until I added the $IsWindows If statement.

@music2myear, I didn't mean to say that winget hangs. Rather, I don't see any evidence in the winget CLI or its PowerShell module wrapper that it actually updates msstore packages — I definitely don't see any documentation stating this. WinGet is actually the sole option that at least appears to function.
